# Click event not working first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I have written a click function in jquery like below and experiencing some problem.

```
$(' #xxx').unbind('click').on('click', function () {
  $('#xxx').removeClass('hide');
  $('#xxx').toggle();
});
```

and the div for the `click` event is

```
<div id="xxx" class="hide"></div>
```

now when i click this `div` nothing appears. Only from the second click the toggle function takes place. Can anyone help me out with this please? I need the click from the first time. And most importantly i dont want the hide function while the page loads because My design breaks while loading and only when the loading is complete it looks nice.So how can i acheive it?

Comment: remove .unbind('click')

Comment: Remove .unbind('click'). It should work

Comment: No i have removed.Even now its the same

Comment: is that inside document ready?

Comment: Your code seems has no problem,maybe post more code will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

here is a working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ac9sg/1/) of what you desire to do.. there is nothing wrong with your code, i dont know but maybe you forgot to import your jquery like this :

```
<script src="YOUR_JQUERY_PATH/JQUERY_FILENAME.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(' #xxx').unbind('click').on('click', function () {
  // $('#xxx').removeClass('hide'); // <- remove this line
  $('#xxx').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        <div id="xxx" class="hide">aaaaaaaaa</div>

        <script>

            $(' #xxx').on('click', function () 
            {
                  $('#xxx').removeClass('hide');
                  $('#xxx').toggle();
            });

            //Another method
            $(' #xxx').click(function() 
            {
                  $('#xxx').removeClass('hide');
                  $('#xxx').toggle();
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: please provide jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

I ve tried many ways.But i still wonder y this isnt working. But when i modified my code like

```
<div id="xxx" style="display:none"></div> 

$(' #xxx').on('click', function () 
{
  $('#xxx').toggle();
});
```

it works like a gem.Anyway i got the output.Still in a confusion y my previous code hasnt worked.